# nginx - auth_request setting url after rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

In my nginx configuration, I have this directive:

```
location /api/v2/compute {
    rewrite (?i)^/api/v2/compute(.*)$ /api/v2/internal$1 break;

    auth_request /enforce;

    proxy_pass http://vm-manager;
}
```

I want to have a /enforce endpoint that will forward (in a header) the URI **after-rewrite**:

```
location = /enforce {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Method $request_method;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri $request_uri;

    proxy_pass http://enforcer;
}
```

The problem is $request_uri contains the original URL, and not the URL after rewrite.
If I use `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri $uri;`, I get the currently-handled URL - `/enforce`.

I've tried to `set $rewrite_uri $uri` in the original location and to `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri $rewrite_uri;` in `/enforce`, but that doesn't work.

Do you know how can I set in auth_request the URL after the rewrite?

Comment: I've tried passing the new uri through query params - "auth_request /enforce?uri=$uri", but apparently query params are not supported with auth_request:
https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to solve it using [ngx_headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module.

```
location /api/v2/compute {
    rewrite (?i)^/api/v2/compute(.*)$ /api/v2/internal$1 break;

    more_set_input_headers "X-Forwarded-Uri: $uri";
    auth_request /enforce;

    proxy_pass http://vm-manager;
}
```